# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-interop

I am trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll in my powershell script. The machine on which i am trying to use don't have Office installed.
I used below code to add the dll

```
Add-Type -LiteralPath "D:\Software\microsoft.office.interop.excel\Office.dll" 
Add-Type -LiteralPath "D:\Software\microsoft.office.interop.excel\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll"
```

when i am trying to create the object using

```
$excel = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
```

I am getting error as:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

All the Office PIAs ([primary interop assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/aax7sdch(v=vs.100))) do is provide a .NET-friendly layer *on top of* the COM APIs provided by the Office applications themselves.

Therefore, they can only work if Office is present as well.
The error you're getting, [`0x80040154`](https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_ITF/0x80040154), indicates that the underlying Excel COM class isn't registered.

(Conversely, it *is* possible for PowerShell to talk to Office without the interop assemblies, and, when authoring code that needs to run on multiple machines, it may be *preferable* not to use them, given that their presence cannot be assumed. [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object)'s `-Strict` switch issues a warning when the interop assemblies are being used.)

---

As for the ability to work with Office documents *without* an Office installation present:

- For *Excel* documents, consider using the popular [`ImportExcel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module.

Comment: thank you much, Is there a way i can open the excel without installing Office in PS?

Comment: I have an excel sheet where in first sheet i have an pivot table and in second sheet i am placing my data. post placing the data, i am refreshing the first sheet (pivot table). is this something i can achieve this importexcel?

Comment: @SA., my guess is: yes. The module is very powerful and does have pivot-table functionality; here's a query that searches for "pivot" among the examples in the repo: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adfinke%2FImportExcel+pivot+path%3A%2F%5EExamples%5C%2F%2F+path%3A%2F%5EExamples%5C%2F%2F+path%3A%2F%5EExamples%5C%2F%2F&type=code The list of all cmdlets, which includes pivot table-related ones, is here: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/tree/master/mdHelp/en

Comment: @SA., I think the answer now fully addresses the question as asked (plus some additional information). If you have follow-up questions regarding the use of `ImportExcel`, I suggest creating new question posts.